# One Race in the Future?

Tags: space, futurology, races

My novel set in the future where everything is automated and fake: lighting, air, and food are all modified or simulated, and the government controls it all. This automated world is set on a planet called Earth 9, which is not really a planet but a large space station housing 2 million people. When I was reading my first chapters draft, I was introducing my main character and I was wondering what is his race. I was thinking would there be just one race, so the government could control religion and racial ideas. That way, racial disagreements wouldn't start nor would it create a war, which in my book is the motto, “Blessed with peace of mind”. But later is found in the online database was originally “Lost With One Mind”. Could the idea of one race be possible.

Comment: Race is a social construct which varies from culture to culture. To give you an illustrative example: are Iranians white people? There is no way to answer this question without taking into account the cultural context. The point is that human races are not natural phenomena, they exist only within a specific culture. So to come to your question: if you want only one race (which means that the culture does not have a concept of human race), go for it. If you want multiple races, go for it, and think what would be the racial attributes perceived by the members of the culture in the novel.

Comment: AlexP again you come with a fine answer and imprison it in the comments!  Why not paste that into an answer and I will up vote it.

Comment: You say "The government controls it all", but what exactly does it control? Does it choose not to control something, i.e. let people be free in any way? What is the punishment, if any, for noncompliance?

Comment: @AlexP I'd suggest that our *responses* to racial differences are cultural, and there are a large number of populations which are +/- hard to tell apart visually (imagine a wide band from sicily to afghanistan), but it seems counterintuitive to me that you can put an Irishman, and Inuit, and a Masai person in a room together and nobody would notice any difference.  You could even make a story element out of it, where the clone-brother squid-aliens can't believe that all the gloriously varied people of Earth are even the same genus!

Comment: @akaloi: Of course they would notice the differences; but they would not necessarily consider them to be *racial* differences. After all, if you put a short person and a tall person in the same room everybody would notice the difference, but I believe that nobody would consider it to be racial. There have been very successful cultures, such as, for example, the classical Greco-Roman culture, which simply did not have a concept of human race; of course the Romans knew that sub-Saharan Africans had very dark skin and northern Europeans very light skin.

Answer (score 1):

By the time we have space stations which can support 2 million people safely, the medical sciences involved in appearance alteration will give those citizen's complete control over their skin color, hair color and all other racially-linked features.  Each person will be able to modify their body's outward appearance with ease, choosing to have a dark complexion today and freckles tomorrow.  With such diversity at hand, the concept of race will loose all meaning.

Are all 2 million residents from a single ancestral (racial) stock?  Who knows!

...and more importantly, who cares.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must answer the question.

What is race?

Race is mainly a social construct sometimes based on physical characteristics such as skin color.

It really depends on what you mean. If all people have the same physical characteristics with no variation, then race is a bit erased. To give you an example, there's the Irish. We had signs that said "Irish need Not apply" back in the day, but because Irish people LOOKED a lot like the English, Dutch, and other stock, they became "White" and Irish became heritage instead of race.

So you could take this a bit further in this dystopia of yours. Not only is the environment constructed, maybe the people are as well. There may well be NO difference in facial features or skin color at all. Everyone may look exactly the same, or there 6 basic faces you are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

One race is simple when all breeding is done by cloning controlled by the government. Everyone is sterile and all birth is controlled artificially.

It's another good means of control.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR -- Absolutely!**

On Earth, races came about when you had populations that didn't mix much.  They had enough time and isolation to diverge.  In more mixed communities, over time you'll get a fair amount of intermarriage.  Note I'm talking about what you might call "visual races", or if you want to be all jargony, "phenotypes".

You might speculate that over time, the races of Earth will gradually meld together into one.  This could happen -- who's to say -- but that job would be much easier in a smaller community such as your space station.

It'll help if the community identity is based on language, culture, alien threats, or some other non-visual criterion.